# Randomly partitioning a set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Writing code, I found that I needed to solve this problem to make an optimal choice of a key constant.

If I have a set of size $l$ , and I randomly choose half of them $x$ times, what is the probability that I did *not* choose all elements (at least once)?

I want to choose $x$ so that the probability is small enough, but I want the least possible value for it. Any ideas?

Comment: So I am not understanding your question quite yet. So you have a set $L$ with $l$ elements, and you want to take some half of the objects in $L$ to form some set $M$ with $l/2$ elements. Then you want to draw elements from $M$ $x$ times? The probability that we do not choose an element, then is taken respect to $M$? Or shall it be to all of $L$?

Comment: @RaymondCheng I will rephrase: I do a random choosing of $l/2$ elements from the **total set** $x$ times, what is the probability that I did not choose 1 or more elements in any of those choosings?

Comment: I think the question is: Choose $x$ subsets $M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_x \subseteq L$, each uniformly at random from all $\binom{|L|}{|L|/2}$ subsets of size $|L|/2$.  What is the probability that $\cup_{i=1}^x M_i \neq L$?  (Hopefully we have $|L| \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question would seem to be this - we have $l=2L$ and we make random choices of $L$ items from $l$ some $m$ times. We want to know (or estimate well) the chance that we don't choose all $l=2L$ items.

Well the number of ways of selecting $L$ items $m$ times is $\binom {2L}{L}^m$

The number of ways of selecting $L$ items, without selecting the $n^{th}$ is $\binom {2L-1}{L}^m$ and the item we don't choose can be selected in $\binom {2L}{1} $ ways. But this double counts the cases where we miss two items. So we have an inclusion-exclusion sum for the number of possibilities where we miss at least one:$$\binom {2L}{1}\binom {2L-1}{L}^m-\binom {2L}{2}\binom {2L-2}{L}^m+\dots (-1)^{r+1}\binom {2L}{r}\binom {2L-r}{L}^m+\dots$$

Putting that together you get the probability you seem to want.

Comment: So optimally I should stop when r=L and divide the total by $\binom{2L}{L}^m$? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @chubakueno Yes - beyond that the binomial coefficients would anyway turn out to be $=0$.